# mysql update datetime column - add 10 year 3 month 22 days and 10 hours, 30 minutes to existing data

Tags: mysql

I have many columns like this:

```
select when from t1 where when LIKE '2002-01-02 %'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
when: 2002-01-02 02:13:14
*************************** 2. row ***************************
when: 2002-01-02 02:15:31
*************************** 3. row ***************************
when: 2002-01-02 02:19:42
```

I am trying to increment the date and time with 10 years, 3 month, 22 days, and 13 hours, 10 minutes, so that it will look something like:

```
2012-04-24 15:23:14
2012-04-24 15:25:31
2012-04-24 15:29:42
```

Searched and found ways ( ADDDATE ) to increase either only the year, or month ... but how can I do for all the year, month, date, and time ?

If it can be done in a single query it would great, but anything is fine .. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you actually have a column named `"when"` ?

Comment: @ypercube, possible as it is no reserved mysql keyword. Otherwise using `` will do.

Comment: @Mike: `WHEN` is reserved, even from MySQL 5.0 version, according to MySQL docs: [Reserved words in 5.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this -

```
SELECT datetime + INTERVAL 10 YEAR + INTERVAL 3 MONTH + INTERVAL 22 DAY
       + INTERVAL 10 HOUR + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AS new_date_time FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server is version 5.5 or newer you can use TO_SECONDS combined with UNIX_TIMESTAMP and FROM_UNIXTIME:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(when) + TO_SECONDS('0010-03-22 13:10:00')) new_when 
FROM t1
WHERE when LIKE '2002-01-02 %'
```